# Change the src of HTML image tag to load image from a url using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, dynamic

Sorry to sound naive since I'm a beginner. I have been trying to load an image on my website with the image hosted somewhere else online and having a url "http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg"

I have an image tag defined as below

```
<img id="image" src="" alt="" />
```

Moreover my javascript function executes the following on a button click

```
document.getElementById("image").src="http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg";
```

The URL seems to work fine, but the image doesn't show up onclick.

Am I making any mistake?

Thanks for any suggestion :)

Comment: Are you sure the correct function triggers on-click?

Comment: Yes I checked that :(

Answer (score 1):

I could see that you are using `"` inside here, may be the HTML would also have `"` so that, it might not work. You can use the following code:

```
<a href="#"
   onclick='document.getElementById("image").src="http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg"; return false'>Change</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. I checked it but that isn't the issue unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I created a Jsfiddle, and it seems to work fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/ltlombardi/jvts4m3y/

```js
var coco = function(){
document.getElementById("image").src="http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Vapor-Rage-Small-Logo-new.png";
};
```

```html
<img id="image" src="" alt="" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="coco()">Click here</a>
```